# sensulib package interface as function param

Tags: go, sensu

I am trying to make use of this golang package: https://github.com/jefflaplante/sensulib

I want to get all the events from the sensu API. I've followed the example code and modified it slightly so it works:

```
config := sensu.DefaultConfig()
config.Address = "sensu-url:port"
onfig.Username = "admin"
config.Password = "password"

// Create a new API Client
sensuAPI, err := sensu.NewAPIClient(config)
if err != nil {
  // do some stuff
}
```

Now I want to grab all the events from the API, and there's a neat function do to that, `GetEvents`

However, the [function](https://github.com/jefflaplante/sensulib/blob/master/event.go#L32) expects a parameter, `out`, which is an interface. Here's the function itself:

```
func (c *API) GetEvents(out interface{}) (*http.Response, error) {
    resp, err := c.get(EventsURI, out)
    return resp, err
}
```

What exactly is it expecting me to pass here? I guess the function wants to write the results to something, but I have no idea what I'm supposed to call the function *with*

I've read a bunch of stuff about interfaces, but it's not getting any clearer. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The empty interface `interface{}` is just a placeholder for anything. It's roughly the equivalent of `object` in Java or C# for instance. It means the library doesn't care about the type of the parameter you are going to pass. For hints about what the library does with that parameter, I suggest you look at the source code.